# Explained Variance in Scikit Learn PCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using PCA in scikit-learn to understand the features in my dataset.

As a result, I am using the following code to extract the explained variance.

```
pca = PCA().fit(df)
result = pd.Series(pca.explained_variance_, index=df.columns)
```

However, according to scikit-learn's code for PCA, explained variance is calculated as:

```
U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / n_samples
```

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765acfa4c5d1ec05fc4b406968ad233c75162/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py

And in Scipy's documentation for svd, S is sorted when it is returned.

> s : ndarray The singular values, sorted in non-increasing order. Of
>   shape (K,), with K = min(M, N).

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html#scipy.linalg.svd

Therefore, there is no relationship between the order of the columns and the order of the explained variance returned by PCA.

As a result, the above code does not work. Is there a way to get the explained variance of each feature?  I am not a statistician, so I may have missed something.

Comment: *"Therefore, there is no relationship between the order of the columns and the order of the explained variance returned by PCA."* I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Which "columns" are you referring to - the columns in your original DataFrame, or the columns of `V` (i.e. your principal components)?

Comment: I am referring to the columns in the original data frame.  My goal is to understand which columns are having the greatest impact on the analysis.

Comment: Just to understand the features in your data set, can't you just look at the summary of your data using `df.describe()`? PCA is going to transform your features into a new set of features (which are linear combinations of the original features), so it does not make sense to try to understand your original features with it. If you are doing regression (or classification), to understand which features have the biggest impact on the response, you can try linear regression (or logistic regression) and inspect the parameters you get along with their p-values.